# Grassmannians $G(k, n)$ and $G(n-k, n)$ are diffeomorphic

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, grassmannian

> Let $f:G(k, n)\to G(n-k, n)$ be the map taking a $k$-plane $V$ (i.e., a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$) into it's orthogonal complement $V^{\perp}$. Show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

My question is whether or not the following strategy can work:

Since $f$ is obviously a bijection, it is enough to prove that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, so the plan is to prove that the linear map $f_{*_{p}}$ has full rank $k(n-k)$ for every $p\in G(k, n)$.

My difficulty is: I'm having trouble to calculate $f_{*_{p}}(v)$ for an arbitrary $v \in T_p(G(k, n))$ because I don't know how to concretely represent such a $v$.

Is this strategy doable? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @anomaly, but even though the problem is the same, my question is actually about this specific strategy of proving that $f_{*_{p}}$ has a full rank. That's where I'm stuck :)

Comment: Although you can think about the tangent spaces of the Grassmannians, all you really need to check is smoothness, because you have the inverse mapping. You can do it in local coordinates easily enough, or you can argue by smoothness of the Hodge star operator on $\Lambda^k \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: That said, it's worth understanding that $T_\xi G(k,n) = \text{Hom}(\xi,\xi^\perp)$.